# Setting up proxy for constructor arguments vs. etc areas

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, di, proxy

Generally it is prefereable to set `.xml` configuration files only for areas that will use it. I want to set some `proxy object for my classes`__construct()` arguments.

In case of models it can be not so sure and maybe it is better to use `etc\di.xml`, but maybe in case of blocks and controllers one can be more specific?

Is it enough, then if I will set `proxy` for frontend blocks and controllers in `etc\frontend\di.xml` or I should do it in `etc\di.xml`?